# Hooks and Api calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm calling my API through AXIOS. My response is coming back, which i can see if i check my network, but it returns empty data when I console.log:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function bt() {
    const authAxios = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    });

    const Data = await authAxios
      .get('/tasks/')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
  bt();
}, []);
```

Comment: What does `setMessage()` do?

Comment: What does your response look like?

Comment: Your code is mangled: there is a `catch` but no `try`. But your question is not really a question.

Answer (score 1):

- 1 - You've used an async function alongside trying to resolve the promise. Either get rid of the async and await or get rid of everything after "await authAxios"(i.e the catch and then blocks)
- 2 -  The reason why res.data console log is blank is because res.data is undefined try changing that line to just res. Check the response Object to see if the info is there.

```
 .then((res) => {
        //console.log(res.data);
          console.log(res)
          setmessage(res.data);
        // this.getUserUpdate(res.data)
        console.log(res.data);
      })
```

For res.data to work you need to make sure that your API creates an attribute called data for the response. If this doesn't work I recommend you also add what your back-end looks like.

Answer (score 1):

As @Pyro mentioned you are mixing up 2 completly different promise-handling techniques.

You'd have to decide to either use `.then()` or `async/await`

e.g.

With `async/await`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function bt() {
    const authAxios = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    });

    const Data = await authAxios.get('/tasks/')
  }
  bt();
}, []);
```

Or with `.then()`

```
useEffect(() => {
  function bt() {
    const authAxios = axios.create({
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
      },
    });

    const Data = authAxios.get('/tasks/').then(console.log).catch(console.log);
  }
  bt();
}, []);
```